# How to initialize a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, filesystems, jtree

I've been trying to make a simple JTree for a program and I'm getting crazy with this.
I just want to make a JTree to show all files and folders inside a given folder.
Anyone can help me with some examples?

Comment: post the codes that you have tried so far

Comment: It took me last than a minute to find this:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm  How much time have you spent researching the subject?

Comment: today was asked similair question about

Comment: You might start with the code for [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html The whole example there is.